# Tracert to Email

Tags: email, batch-file, traceroute

I'd like to receive result of tracert information from my customer, however, they are not IT savvy.

Is there any ways we can get the tracert result be sent to an email or a web-form?

Any written bat files or open source programme available?

Comment: cut and paste is not particularly difficult or IT savvy.

Comment: @ChrisBint I'd imagine it's the "open up the command line, run tracert" part, not the copy/paste part. Although I do recall copy/paste being a pain in the Windows command line in many versions.

Comment: We are not able to give direct support to our end customer who experience high latency to our website. It would be simpler for them to open up a bat files or whatsoever, that allow them to send those details to us seamlessly

Comment: Sending email isn't uniform across environments. It cannot be done simply in batch. You could use VBA/Outlook (if you have them) or some real programming language (Perl, Python, PowerShell, etc.) if you have them in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

`clip.exe` sends stuff to the clipboard.

You could put this into a batch file.

```
tracert targethost | clip
```

Then have them run the batch file and paste (the batch file did the copy—the client doesn't need to select/highlight anything) into an email. Surely non-savvy clients can send email.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote an alternative solution that allow users to upload their traceroute result using a bat file.

> IPADDRESS - The ip Address that you'd like to trace
>  USERNAME - The
>   FTP username
>  PASSWORD - The Password for the FTP user
>  HOSTNAME
>   - The FTP Host name

Create a traceroute.bat

> ```
> @echo off
> for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
> set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
> set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
>
> set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
>
> ECHO Please wait....
>
> tracert IPADDRESS > tracert-%fullstamp%.log
> echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
> echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
> echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
> echo put tracert-%fullstamp%.log>> ftpcmd.dat
> echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
>
> ECHO Please allow FTP to upload the results...
>
> ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat HOSTNAME
> del ftpcmd.dat
> del tracert-%fullstamp%.log
>
> ECHO Uploading complete! You may now exit
> @pause
> ```